# How to add module libraries to the page through an admin page?

Tags: 8, hooks

Looking for some guidance on how to create a custom module, `mymodule`, that will pull all the libraries from the custom module and display it in an admin screen. Once the libraries are displayed, I want to be able to set `Add to Pages` (checkbox) for each library to determine if it should be added to the nodes. It would be ideal if the setting became a configuration.

The goal is to be able to add any libraries I need to the custom module, but selectively add them to nodes using [hook_page_attachments](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments/8.5.x). How would I do this?

I initially tried this, but couldn't find a way to get all the libraries.

**mymodule.libraries.yml**

```
library1:
  version: 1.x
  header: true
  js:
    path/to/library/file1.js

library2:
  version: 1.x
  js: 
    /path/to/library/file2.js
```

**mymodule.module**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments().
 */
function mymodule_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
  $libraries = [
    'mymodule/library1',
    'mymodule/library2',
  ];

  foreach($libraries as $library) {
    $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = $library;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you only want to add the libraries to nodes, then rather than using `hook_page_attachments()` which will affect all pages, you could use [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your module is referencing the library names wrong. It should be “mymodule/library_name” instead of just the library name.

As long as you get that right, it wouldn’t be hard to loop node field values or a config object and add them like that.

Comment: updated the code to have proper library names. Are you considering a config object one option, but another one could be to have a field on a particular content type that would add the libraries?

Comment: Depends on how you want to offer the option, but as long as the names are correct, you can loop and attach them all the same.

Comment: If you store whether to add the libraries in a config/content entity, don't forget to add it as a cacheable dependency to the page to ensure pages get flushed when the entity is changed. (IIUC you should add the dependency even if you're not attaching a library - that way when you later configure it to add the library the cache will be flushed appropriately.)

Comment: @Andy is this what you are referring to [CacheableDependencyInterface & friends](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api/cacheabledependencyinterface-friends)?

Comment: @usernameabc yup - that page gives the theory, and you can find an example [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/cacheability-of-render-arrays#concrete-example).

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
js:
    path/to/library/file1.js
```

With

```
js:
    path/to/library/file1.js: {}
```